# box shadow on an ipad / safari

Tags: ipad, safari, input, focus, css

I'm having trouble adding the nice shadow on focus for an input box on my ipad for safari.

Here's my code

```
/* remember to define focus styles! */
:focus {
    outline: 0;
}    
input[type=text]{
        width: 494px;

        height: 44px;
        line-height: 44px;
        font-size: 24px;
        border: 2px solid #666666;
    }
    input:focus{
      -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 15px #ffffff;
       -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 15px #ffffff;
       box-shadow:0 0 15px #ffffff;
    }
```

I'm using eric meyer's reset. 
I want it to look like this:
 [image]

Any ideas?

Thanks guys.

Jason

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I have the same problem but I found the solution:

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
```

However it does not work when there is an inset shadow.

Comment: I can confirm this works for inset box shadows on text input fields on iPad 3 Safari.

Answer (score 5):

```
<input type="text" name="success" value="fail">
```

No dice people, ipad hasn't got support for this which is so useless, chrome is it!

Update:

`-webkit-appearance: none;` FTW

Answer (score 2):

In my case, setting border-radius solved my problem.

```
border-radius: 1px;
```

Comment: This is actually the only answer that worked for me for iPhone 6plus.