# iPhone iOS will not display box-shadow properly

Tags: ios, webkit, css, mobile-webkit

## The Design

The contact form on a responsive design has input fields with both an inset shadow and regular outside shadow. See image below.

[image: Input Field Design on Mobile]

---

## The Code

```
input {
    background:#fff;
    height:auto;
    padding:8px 8px 7px;
    width:100%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    border:#fff solid 3px;
    border-radius:4px;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25), inset 2px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
```

---

## The Issue

iOS v4+ does not display the box-shadow properly. See image below.

[image: Input box-shadow rendered incorrectly]

---

## Tested

I have attempted using -webkit-box-shadow.

```
-webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25),
                   inset 2px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
```

I have applied `display:block;` to the input element.

---

## Current Workaround

I would prefer not having to do this, but this is the only way I can get my desired effect.

**HTML**

```
<p><input /></p>
```

**CSS**

```
p {
   width:50%;
   box-sizing:border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
   -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
   box-shadow:0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .35);
   border-radius:4px;
}

    input {
        background:#fff;
        height:auto;
        padding:8px 8px 7px;
        width:100%;
        box-sizing:border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
        -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
        border:#fff solid 3px;
        border-radius:4px;
        box-shadow:inset 2px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    }
```

Even with this workaround, the inset shadow on iOS is not rendered properly; but it's close enough.

---

## My Question

Is it possible to have multiple instances of box-shadow on a single element render properly on iOS devices? If not, what about the inset shadow? Or am I using this property and its values incorrectly?

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: May be worth noting that I tested without the `box-shadow` and it looked the same.

Answer (score 214, accepted):

Try adding `-webkit-appearance: none;` iOS tends to mess up forms.

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but the answer was also given on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902629/box-shadow-on-an-ipad-safari, just not accepted.  I'm glad this answer was accepted here.

Comment: and remember to put it before box-shadow, not after

Comment: It's been approx. 3 years, but `iOS tends to mess up forms` .. I have to vote this up :'-) Note: iOS box-shadow will need 3 things. 1) Vendor Prefix on the box-shadow `-webkit-box-shadow: ...` 2) Border Radius set, example to 1px `border-radius: 1px` 3) disabled appearance `-webkit-appearance: none;`

Comment: Adding `-webkit-box-shadow: ..` and `-moz-box-shadow: ..` will provide the deepest possible browser support.

Answer (score 3):

I had a problem trying to add a box-shadow around invalid inputs (before submit is clicked).

Using `-webkit-appearance: none;` worked fine for a while, but I've noticed on chrome checkboxes have gone missing now.

Here's my hack that works more or less cross browser. Looks like safari is the new "internet explorer" :-/

```css
input:invalid, select:invalid, textarea:invalid, .invalid {
    background-clip: padding-box; /* Safari fix */
    box-shadow: 0 0 5pt 2pt rgba(255,0,0,.75) !important;
}

select:invalid {
    border: 1px solid red; /* Safari fix */
}

input[type="checkbox"]:invalid{
    background: red; /* Safari fix */
}

input[type="radio"]:invalid{
    background: red; /* Safari fix */
}
```

[image: iPhone Safari]
[image: Other browsers]