# CSS Box Shadow not working on iPhone

Tags: html, css

For some reason I can't get the CSS box-shadow to show up on Safari or Chrome on my iPhone.  Here is the code:

```
input.error {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 1px rgba(224, 39, 14, 1);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 1px rgba(224, 39, 14, 1); 
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 1px rgba(224, 39, 14, 1);
}
```

The code is being used on HTML Input fields, would this cause any problems?  What am I doing wrong?

Shows up in browser fine...

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone iOS will not display box-shadow properly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757146/iphone-ios-will-not-display-box-shadow-properly)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

If this in a form block, add

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
```

iPhones can mess up forms. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757146/iphone-ios-will-not-display-box-shadow-properly).

Comment: solved my problem box shadow wasnt showing up in mobile safari

Comment: there is an important comment in the link's answer by Johansrk: "
and remember to put it before box-shadow, not after"

Answer (score 6):

Try adding `-webkit-appearance: none;` iOS tends to mess up forms.

Answer (score 2):

Because you write it mistake
try this:

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 1px rgba(224, 39, 14, 1);
```

you just write 3 size for it

Answer (score 2):

I've tried EVERYTHING listed on the internet to fix this issue in a static sense.  The ONLY thing I could get to work was to use the -webkit-box-shadow styling, but to add #222 like so:

-webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0.5px 1px 1px #222);

Comment: this works - but take note that this resets the ordering for css stacking. i.e. z-index will cease to work normally. refer to https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/4-reasons-your-z-index-isnt-working-and-how-to-fix-it-coder-coder-6bc05f103e6c/

Answer (score 0):

In my case I fixed adding ALL these rules:

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
border:0;
border-radius: 1px;
height: 1px;
```

In particular setting also the `height`.