# Tailwind CSS class "ring-inset" applied to form inputs is not visible on iPhone

Tags: css, forms, next.js, tailwind-css

I am styling form inputs in my Next.js project using Tailwind CSS classes.

Here is how I have styled form inputs:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { cn } from "@/lib/util";

interface InputProps extends React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement> {}

const Input = React.forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, InputProps>(
  ({ type, className, ...props }, ref) => {
    return (
      <input
        type={type}
        className={cn(
          "h-10 w-full rounded-md border-0 px-3 py-2 shadow bg-transparent ring-1 ring-inset ring-neutral-200 transition ease-out placeholder:text-neutral-400 focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:outline-none focus:ring-neutral-400 sm:text-sm",
          className,
        )}
        ref={ref}
        {...props}
      />
    );
  },
);

Input.displayName = "Input";

export { Input };
```

As you can see, instead of a border, I have applied ring to the input. The relevant classes are: `border-0 ring-1 ring-inset ring-neutral-200`. This works as expected except on mobile devices.

When I see my login form using chrome dev tools in responsive mode, I do see the ring and the shadow around the input:

[image]

However, when I actually visit my site on my iPhone, I don't see any ring around the inputs:

[image]

Can you help me understand why this is happening?

You can take a look at the login form at the following link:

https://www.hemantasundaray.com/login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since tailwind uses `box-shadow` under the hood for the `ring-*` classes, and sometimes iOS devices tend to mess forms up, you can set the input style to this:

```css
input {
  -webkit-appearance: none !important;
}
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757146/iphone-ios-will-not-display-box-shadow-properly)